# R: displaying scientific notation

Tags: r

```
chocolate <- data.frame(
  Sabor =
  c(5, 7, 3,
    4, 2, 6,
    5, 3, 6,
    5, 6, 0,
    7, 4, 0,
    7, 7, 0,
    6, 6, 0,
    4, 6, 1,
    6, 4, 0,
    7, 7, 0,
    2, 4, 0,
    5, 7, 4,
    7, 5, 0,
    4, 5, 0,
    6, 6, 3
  ),
Tipo = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 15)),
Provador = factor(rep(1:15, rep(3, 15))))
tapply(chocolate$Sabor, chocolate$Tipo, mean)
ajuste <- lm(chocolate$Sabor ~ chocolate$Tipo + chocolate$Provador)
summary(ajuste)
anova(ajuste)
a1 <- aov(chocolate$Sabor ~ chocolate$Tipo + chocolate$Provador)
posthoc <- TukeyHSD(x=a1, 'chocolate$Tipo', conf.level=0.95)

  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = chocolate$Sabor ~ chocolate$Tipo + chocolate$Provador)

$`chocolate$Tipo`
           diff       lwr       upr     p adj
B-A -0.06666667 -1.803101  1.669768 0.9950379
C-A -3.80000000 -5.536435 -2.063565 0.0000260
C-B -3.73333333 -5.469768 -1.996899 0.0000337
```

Here is some sample code using `TukeyHSD`. The output is a matrix, and I want the values to be displayed in scientific notation. I've tried using `scipen` and setting `options(digits = 20)` but some of my values from my actual data are still way too small so that the p adj values are 0.00000000000000000000

How can I get the values to be displayed in scientific notation?

Comment: `lm(Sabor ~ Tipo + Provador, data=chocolate)` and also `aov(..., data=...)` are shorter. BTW: what is your alpha (significance level)?

Comment: I didn't specify an alpha, so I assume it's the default (0.05?)

Comment: Normally you have to know the alpha in your discipline. And yes, often it is 0.05 = 5%.  To decide the test you have to compare the p-value with your alpha. So why do you want to see so much digits for the small p-values? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
format(posthoc, scientific = TRUE)
```

If you want to change the number of digits, for instance using 3, you could do this:

```
format(posthoc, scientific = TRUE, digits = 3)
```